# How to change ui-grid with gridOption-enableRowselection dynamically in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to enable and disable rowSelection for view depending on some condition. Problem here is,multiple views use the same html and controller. I need the rowSelection to be disabled for a certain view and enabled in other cases.

I have tried these.
1)Assigned a function for enableRowselection which would return boolean.(Didn't work)
2)Tried with isRowSelectable too.(Didn't work)

Code is as below.Not sure if it is implemented in right way. I'm a beginner in AngularJS and ui-grid
1)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableRowSelection: isSelectionEnabled
}
 isSelectionEnabled():boolean {
             var seletionEnabled = true;
             if (doesn't satisfy condition) {
                seletionEnabled = false;
             }
            return seletionEnabled ;
         }
```

2)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
isRowSelectable: function() {
                 if(satisfies condition) return true; 
                return false; 
               },
}
```

Comment: Any solution would depend on the "condition", I think. It is not clear to me why you can't just assign true or false to gridoptions enableRowSelection attribute once you determine whether or not to enable rowselection....
Could you elaborate on the "condition"?

Comment: Whether row selection has to be enabled or not depends on the condition in the function. And since this same controller is used by other  views, i want the value of enableRowselection value to be set dynamically depending on the return value from the function.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know if you want to enable rowselection on creation of the ui-grid. 
Try something like:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

  $scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection = $scope.isSelectionEnabled();
};

$scope.isSelectionEnabled = function() {
  // some logic here to determine whether to enable rowselection or not
  return true; // or false
};
```

You can pretty much change `$scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection` anywhere, once the ui-grid has been created.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8JwKta0g7FGhC3KN2yR?p=preview) for an example and/or to try out if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to know ,is there any way to call a function from html page for the same?I don't want to use button. Anywhere else i can call? Function being written in the controller.

Comment: Maybe use classes in the HTML of the ui-grid. I updated the Plunker to demonstrate. Look for classes "with-selection" / "without-selection" in the index files, and isSelectionEnabled function.

Answer (score 0):

the right property is "enableRowSelection", try the following:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: function () { 

     if(condition){
            return true
      } 
      return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. It is not returning value got from function.